# CSS limit repeated background img from overflowing body

Tags: css, background-image, sprite, repeat, tile

I'm trying to limit the repeated body background image (some call it sprite) from overflowing the bottom.

The reason I'm using the `before:` method, is because it was the only solution I could find to add transparency to background image transparent without causing everything else to have transparency.

I notice whenever I pull `content: " "` style, the overflow is removed correctly, but the image disappears causing it's necessity. It's the image wanting to finish displaying in its entirety that's causing the extra scrollable space below the body.

I have tried various combinations of `background-size`, `overflow`, even `background-position` (which is kind of not really related to this).

The background tile is rather large 528x290px, and this is a responsive site.

Here is the code im working with

jade

```
body
  div#body-wall
```

sass

```
#body-wall:before{ //background image
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: -264px; //set half image dimension to remote initial offset
  top: -250px;
  background-image: $body-bg-image;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  // background-size: 528px 290px; //actual image dimensions 528x290
  // width:190%; //set wider to accomodate for top and left offset
  // height:120%; //set wider to accomodate for top and left offset
  opacity: .15;
  content: '';
}
#body-wall{ //implemented for background image
  position: relative; //important for background image to display
}
```

The reason I have the top and left offset is to get the image to a nice starting position.  Please note, adjusting the top and or left positioning does nothing to fix the issue.

What can I do to tweak the styles to get the image to cutoff, using this `before:` method.

**EDIT**
What Im seeing in my development site, there is an additional few hundred pixels of overflowed image causing the bottom of the site to fall below well below the footer div (see fiddle).

**Expected result**, I expect the image to be clipped off at the bottom of the content, as opposed to causing the content boxes to expand until its finished displaying leaving a few hundred px of overlap.

I was able to recreate what I'm seeing, its in [this fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fkvh22gL/3/), but i had to actually comment out the position relative in the `#body-wall` for some reason, where on my development site, if i do this, the bg disappears entirely to a blank white.

```
#body-wall {
    /* position: relative; */
}
```

Please note, I have an entire `bootstrap3`, then migrated to `bs4` site in the middle of that tempdiv.  Also note, migrating `bs` had no effect on the way its displaying like this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `overflow: hidden` on body?

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, it only removes a trivial amount, a few pixels which im not really sure what is, but it still leaves a couple hundred px to be reckoned with, so im looking for a full stop measure.

Comment: Could you please make a jsfiddle or codepen or whatever snippet showing your problem? Also the expected result is not clear.